# Happy Mask Salesman Mask

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda, majoras-mask

At the end of the game (in the original N64 version of The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask; this was seemingly removed in the 3DS remaster), the Happy Mask Salesman, an ever-disturbing character, makes some characteristically bemusing statements and vanishes without a trace. However, on the exact frame he begins to disappear ([see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZpz5ZuV0MI&list=PL47A5C783DE2E54F7&index=37&t=482s)), his character model changes around a bit, shifting his masks around his backpack and adding one more at the back.

This mask seems to represent himself.

The Happy Mask Salesman is obviously more than he appears. He jerkily teleports around, can summon pipe organs on a whim, somehow knows one of the most powerful songs in any of the worlds, and is after the power of Majora's Mask. And now, right as he vanishes, a mask of his face appears on his back.

Given the above information, it's pretty likely that it is a transformation mask, akin to the Deku Scrub, Darmani, Mikau, Giant, and the Fierce Deity.

What else might this mask imply? Does this lend any further information on the Salesman's identity and/or intentions? Does it mean he's the same salesman as from Ocarina of Time? Could this explain why he shows up in a completely different timeline? And most specifically, why was it removed in the remake? Answers would be appreciated.

Comment: *"his character model changes around a bit, shifting his masks around his backpack and adding one more at the back."* - if you're referring to how he disappears this would be more from how he was rendered. it's a waste to render anything that the player wont see so in a way the models are "hollow". think about it as if you're looking at a glass tube and you draw a face on the opposite side. this is why you're seeing the spooky looking mask on the top-left in 7:37 on the right when he fades away

Comment: (cont') as for adding a new mask, i think you're talking about the yellow thing in the sorta center of the backpack when he fades away, that's his face however the texture for the face itself wouldn't be applied to the inside of the model

Comment: @Memor-X I work with 3D models, and can confirm that the model itself changes, not just the shaders. I studied this for a good while, going frame by frame (and also examining a ripped model). There is indeed a significant change in the geometry, and the texture on the new mask does not seem to be present in the normal model.

Comment: could you post a screenshot because i am seeing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTY1q.jpg) and that looks like the backside of his face without the face texure

Comment: @Memor-X I went back to the footage, and realized that you are probably right. Some of the things I attributed to geometry changes likely are just transparency artifacts. I had neglected some of the items on his front that created that illusion. Mea culpa. :-)

Comment: Majora's Mask is a direct sequel to Ocarina of Time; the Happy Mask Salesman we see in Majora's Mask is almost certainly the same one from Ocarina of Time. As for the mask of himself, I suspect you're unlikely to get a definitive answer to that.

Comment: Also it might be worthwhile breaking your questions down and asking them on the Arqade StackExchange. As it's focused on gaming, there's a greater chance of someone with knowledge of the game seeing the questions.